# How to get statistics of in- and outgoing mails?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I would like to have a statistic that shows me in- and outgoing mails per month. The count would totally suffice.

TBH I don't have much experience with either `Exchange 2003` or `Windows Server 2003`, so I need your help.

Are there any built-in tools to analyze mail traffic? Any log files that can be used?

In addition, we also send many in-house mails, so it would be nice to have them excluded (they all have the same @domain.my ending).

Comment: Enable logging. Read the logs! Run quries on Logs... etc https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/265139